# What is the terminology for retraining neural network with batch of new accumulated recent data after training?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Is there a terminology for retraining trained neural network
with recently obtained data?
I think we could use online learning when training whenever new data comes, but what could I say that if I want to update after gathering certain amount of new data?
Batch retraining? or batch adaptation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that retraining is a correct word. At the same time I believe you might be better off seeking academic literature for vocabulary and definitions rather than using Stackoverflow. I think that StackOverflow might not provide you with what you are looking for.

Here are some publications that can be helpful in your further research:

**Advanced Data Forecasting using Retraining Neural Network Technique:**
- http://tucs.fi/publications/attachment.php?fname=TR542.pdf

**A Retraining Improvement of Feedforward Neural Networks:**
- http://tucs.fi/publications/attachment.php?fname=TR504.pdf